# Django creating superuser and admin module

Tags: django

Hi I am new to Django and following the Django documentation on their official website.
I created a super user with:
`python manage.py createsuperuser`
and provided all the details.

Then I ran the server and opened chrome. I am able to see the admin page but when I provide the credentials the server is stopping automatically.
When I run the server again, I am not able to see that admin login page too unless I delete cookies, open a new browser tab and run the server again.

Can anyone help me over this? Let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can set LOGIN_URL config to url of the admin login page in settings.py like this:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/admin/login/'
```

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately I still cant get the administration page after login. Once I click on Login, it keeps on loading for some time and then displaying 'This site can't be reached'. The local server too is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can see the admin page at `/admin/` on your local domain.
Please provide a detailed error in case.

Refer to the Django docs for more info.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#start-the-development-server

Comment: Thank you. I could see the default /admin/ page. But when I created a superuser and ran the server, I am not able to login. When I enter the details and hit login, my local server is automatically getting turned off. I have to re run the server and this time if I want to view the admin page itself, I had to delete cookies. I had 'django.contrib.admin', under my installed apps in settings.py. I have not changed any code. I just created a superuser

Comment: @SandeepVarma Could you check any error trace while local server turnoff?